# There are some unwanted folders out of nowhere when copying, is this a bug?

Tags: copy

I was trying to copy a folder named `notalentgeek-wiki-pending` from my Dropbox folder into Desktop.

However, the resultant folder has an unwanted folder that does not exist in the source folder.

Is this intended? How can I know for sure, that if I copy a directory it is completely the same as the source directory?

[image].

Comment: Test it. If you see that dropbox adds content to files/folders, ask dropbox why. The question doesn't seem to be related to Ubuntu.

Comment: It is not related to Dropbox. I coped the file into Desktop not Dropbox. All files in my Dropbox are all according to what I need. However, the operating system messed it up when the folder copied. I have turned off and uninstall Dropbox as well. It is the same.